# Как включить отображение ActionBar и StatusBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

Новый проект, в режиме Design activity_main.xml не отображаются ActionBar и StatusBar. Подскажите  пожалуйста, как их включить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: измените тему и будет вам счастье, и посмотрите так же может у вас в xml что-то намудрено

Comment: Пробовал, к сожалению не помогло. В файле xml вроде бы всё стандартно.

Comment: а какая сейчас тема у вас стоит?

Comment: При создании проекта с пустым Activity, в файле манифеста выбрана тема AppTheme.

Comment: тут еще может быть такая штука - превью это временами тупит и работает некорректно, если на эмуляторе/реальном устройстве нету этих виджетов то тогда да это проблема, на это ориентироваться лучше не нужно.

Comment: В эмуляторе всё в порядке. Тогда я вас понял, спасибо за ответ. Надеюсь в дальнейшем всё появится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за ответы, но всё оказалось намного проще, нужно было зайти в View Options и включить Show Layout Decorations.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вам нужно контекст вашей активити через `tools` добавить в корневой `layout` контейнер в разметке `activity_main`:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```